# How technically challenging is making a new CMS optimized for semantic searching?

Tags: node.js, web, content-management-system, strapi, embedding

I'm a freelance web developer who just finished my first project from a client a couple of weeks ago.

Recently I'm digging into the field of semantic searching, chat completion, and text-to-image, mainly using OpenAI and vector databases like Pinecone. I believe these technologies can bring some more value to my potential clients.

So that led me to think about building my own CMS just optimized for semantic searching using vector embeddings. Unlike most CMS services like Strapi or Sanity, I hope my CMS to do such things:

1. Synchronized data CRUD operations between normal databases (like PostgreSQL) and vector databases.
   e.g., If I update, say, an entry in the "Person" collection, a vector embedding targeting it should be updated as well.
2. Endpoints to semantically search entries in the collection.
3. (if necessary) Periodical consistency checking to ensure the one-to-one match between vector embeddings and data in the normal database.
4. semantic querying of collections in the CMS admin panel.
5. (optional) Roles and Permissions

For now, I'm just using Strapi with customized endpoints and controllers for my semantic search services, accompanied by an additional content-managing page for users to update, delete, and create new items to be searched.

I'm not too familiar with working with SQL databases and overall CMS structures since I've been using CMS services and never really built APIs before. What do you think about my idea? Would it be too challenging for me to build it on my own? Or else, will there be an alternative way to do it easily?

( English is not my native language. So sorry if there are grammatical or spelling mistakes ;) )

I'm using Strapi for now.